# Unhide sheets names using VBA whose name contain specific word

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, tabs, hidden

Using the code below where I'm able to select all sheets that contains the word "ba" on it however, if those sheets/tabs are hidden, I can't, I get a "Run-time errror '1004':" warning.

Any suggestion how could I make this code work with hidden sheet/tabs? So it shows all sheets/tabs names with "ba" even if it's hidden shows up? If they are hidden, I want them to appear or .Visible = True

```
Sub listray()
Dim ws As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
For Each ws In Sheets
If LCase(ws.Name) Like "*ba*" Then
    ws.Select Not flg
    flg = True
End If
Next
End Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to `Select` the sheet?

Comment: By select, I been unhide sheets that contain certain text in the name.

Comment: You don't need to `Select` a sheet to hide/unhide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sheets have to be visible to be selected.

```
If LCase(ws.Name) Like "*ba*" Then
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ws.Select Not flg
    flg = True
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to `Select` a worksheet to hide/unhide it. This will cycle through sheets and only leave sheets visible that have name `Like "*ba*"`

```
Sub listray()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Visible = LCase(ws.Name) Like "*ba*"
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is also valid if all that needs to be done is the unhiding. It's unclear if there are followup actions after the sheets are selected though and the OP's reply to your question didn't really make it any less of an unknown. I'm giving this answer an upvote based on the comment reply that said the select was just to perform the unhide.

Comment: Yea that's what i'm basing this answer on. If it doesn't fit OPs need, and the Boolean flag is used for other things, than maybe this will do for future readers :p